# Выбрать IP для исходящих запросов

Tags: ubuntu

Сервер с Ubuntu 18 c несколькими IP адресами от хостера, прописанными в /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml.

Как узнать и изменить IP адрес сервера, с которого должны идти исходящие запросы, например, скриптами php или администратором из командной строки по ssh?

Comment: `$ ip r get 8.8.8.8` — узнаете значение поля src в пакетах, отправляемых на ip 8.8.8.8. глобально изменить можно, указав требующееся значени src в нужном маршруте.

Answer (score 0):

> Как узнать

```
$ ip r get 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp0s0 src 192.168.0.21 uid 1000 
    cache
```

`src 192.168.0.21` — то, что будет использоваться в поле src исходящих ip-пакетов, отправляющихся к `8.8.8.8`.

---

> изменить

если требуется глобально, то, например, так:

```
$ sudo ip r ch $(ip r sh default) src ip.адрес
```

при условии, конечно, что у вас в таблице маршрутизации main содержится только один маршрут по умолчанию, и нет никаких других влияющих на выбор «обратного» адреса маршрутов и/или правил маршрутизации и/или правил netfilter-а.